# Where can I find logs of AWS ECS with AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am using AWS ECS service with EC2 instance, I trying to run a docker springboot container on EC2. Where can I find my logs for that EC2 instance? Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried [CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-logging-monitoring.html)?

Comment: What do you mean by "with EC2 instance"?   Are you using EC2 launch type?  If you don't know the exact logs and log location the ECS log collector can be the best way to grab all the logs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-logs-collector.html CloudWatch will have logs only if you're specifying it in your task definition